# Can you use AJAX calls with Android?

Tags: jquery, android, ajax

I'm a C# web-developer.  And on a daily basis I'm very comfortable using jQuery and making AJAX calls for data (which I love).  However, I am a complete **NOOB** to Android.  My current reading shows Android uses REST'ful services for data-exchange.

So my question(s) are...

**Can Android use jQuery mobile?**
**Can you make normal AJAX calls in Android?**
**Can you ONLY make REST'ful calls in Android?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classic Android development is done in Java. jQuery is largely useless here, as jQuery is for JavaScript, not Java.

However, through tools like PhoneGap, it is possible to create Android applications that are written in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. In this case, you are welcome to use jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, or any other mobile-flavored library you want.

With that in mind:

> Can Android use jQuery mobile?

Only if you are creating a PhoneGap application (distributable through the Market) or are creating a plain HTML5 Web app.

> Can you make normal AJAX calls in Android?

Since AJAX, by definition, is a browser concept, it is the same answer as above.

> Can you ONLY make REST'ful calls in Android?

You can do whatever your little heart desires, so long as you find a Java library (or JavaScript library, for PhoneGap/HTML5) that supports it. Android tends to use plain HTTP requests versus SOAP or XML-RPC, simply because most of the interesting stuff online is accessed via plain HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) if you want to use jQuery. The browser is what calls the javascript (jQuery) obviously Android isn't a browser, it's an OS.

Comment: Can a WebView be used in an application you would sell in the Android Marketplace?

Comment: It can be, however if you want to write Android applications you need to learn java. Google for "commonsware" and buy his books. They are excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation.  You "can" develop in C# using MonoDroid.

Comment: Why? Android is wrote in java, learn it, it'll help you in the long run!

Comment: It was merely meant as an FYI.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to react like a twat. I apoligise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [AQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/), a jQuery-like extension on Android which support asynchronous tasks, ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the assumption that you are referring to in browser code. 
And I have a mobile web app that uses Sencha Touch and PHP calls. Everything seems to work well, though sometimes JSON can really slow things down if you aren't careful how much you send back. Be mindful that the power of Android devices varies greatly from 524 mhz to 2+Ghz and looping through all of that stuff can be taxing.

If you are referring to Native code, I found a library at one point in time that let you do GETs and POSTs in its Java. But I don't know enough about Androids development from the software side to give you any firm answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much a question of whether you can do it on Android.
It's still a browser issue. However any modern cellphones browser will support javascript as well as AJAX. So yes you can use AJAX and jQuery Mobile, as long as this is just a site.

An app is a different story.

Comment: Okay, I want to create an Android application.  So if that is a different story, can you please expand on that idea?

Comment: As dotty said, you'll need to use a webview in your app, then load the html pages from there. Android has it's own API for making calls across HTTP. I've never used it before so beyond that I can't help much. A solution is to host a website then just have an app that's literally a webview that points to your site. However I'd suggest using the native functionality of Android's Development API.

Comment: I must not be communicating well.  Is there a difference between an application you would purchase in the Android Market and an application you would expose through Androids Browser?  I ask because I want to learn to create applications for the Android Market.

Comment: Yes there is, for app development(apps available in the marketplace)  see: http://developer.android.com/index.html. I believe the API is for Java. jQuery won't be of much use for you in this.