# Need Native Android/Java Method to Query Online Search Field

Tags: java, android, post, get

I'd like to query a .cfm page via Android but I'm not sure what method I should be using to do so - any suggestions?

Example:

http://www.sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=smith&fname=

P.S.

Would I use something along the lines of this?

http://androidexample.com/AsyncroTask_Example_To_Get_Server_Data_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=59&aaid=84

Answer (score 0):

use an ajax call with the url with the appropriate first and last name parameters, and then extract the result table from the return value.

see a working jsfiddle sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/FhHXK/

code:

```
$('#get').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.sheriff.org/apps/arrest/results.cfm?lname=a&fname=b',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function (data){
        var result = $(data).find('table.datagrid');
        console.log(result.html());
        $('body').append(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work? It seems like you cant make ajax calls via android:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080884/can-you-use-ajax-calls-with-android

Comment: I'm actually using phonegap in my application which lets me use javascript, so if you don't plan on using anything similar, maybe this won't be the right solution for you.

Comment: Yeah. I'd rather not use phonegap - do you know of any other method of querying that page without using phonegap?

Comment: in my code, I'm using the ajax method from jquery to call httpget on the url specified, it seems like the link that you've found does exactly that, all you need to do should just be parsing the response from the get.